# How to print 2 excel tabs to PDF using python on Linux (not Windows)

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pdf, fpdf, win32com

I am working on Linux (Strictly Centos Type Linux) and using python3
I have some Microsoft Excel (xlsx) files that I am pulling from an FTP server, and I need to generate a PDF from 2 tabs having print formatted areas.
(I am using the word Print, because I cannot copy data to dataframe and create PDF from it. That will not suffice, as these are reports that have formatting. Hence they need to be printed to PDF)

I am unable to create a PDF out of it, on Linux.
AFAIK, win32com will not work on Linux. Also, I need the script to be automated without manual intervention.

Any help or suggested articles are welcome!

Thanks,
K3

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible on a Linux distro as a copy of Excel must be fully installed and accessible. Otherwise, you can use the Win32 api (Need to have Windows).
https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/